# Thinking about time value of an option

Tags: options, option-pricing

In addition to Wikipedia, YouTube and other internet sources, I'm reading Timothy Crack's "Basic Black-Scholes: Option pricing and trading". Most of these sources suggest that it is fairly obvious that an option has time-value. But I am not yet convinced -- could someone please clarify the following reasoning.

To me it seems that any time-value an (American) option might have is due pretty much exclusively to the *volatility* of the underlying asset (and partly on the riskless rate, but I'd like to ignore this for now), and so an option on a hypothetical asset with no volatility should have no time-value. My reasoning is as follows: suppose first that we have a hypothetical asset with no volatility (suppose also that the riskless rate is zero). This means the asset's price is deterministic. In this case, the value of a call option must be [the present value of] $\text{max}(S_m - K,0)$ where $S_m$ denotes the maximum that the spot price ever reaches (possibly infinite) and $K$ denotes the strike price. This remains the value of the call until the (first) time $t=t_1$ that the underlying asset reaches price $S_m$. After that time, the value of the option becomes $\text{max}(S_{m,2}-K,0)$ where $S_{m,2}$ is the highest price the underlying asset reaches after $t_1$, and so on. Indeed this reasoning does demonstrate that the option value changes in time but not because of "time-value". In particular one could exercise the option at time $t=0$ thereby obtaining the stock at the strike price $K$ and then simply wait until time $t=t_1$ (assuming it exists) to sell it, thus realizing the maximum value of the option without holding it beyond time $t=0$. This strategy would be the same whether time $t_1$ is tomorrow or next year, and so the value is the same in both cases, thus the value is independent of time to any maturity date of the option. So, since there seems to be no time-value when the volatility is zero, any time-value must be entirely due to non-zero volatility.

Where am I going wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think its since you're taking the hypothetical situation of the stock deterministically having the same price for each time.

Yes, in that case it would not have time value.

But usually we think of it as the future being ucertain, and the assumtion for time value is that the longer the duration till expiery, the more value there is for speculation.

If some option expires in an hour, then the price will be much more determinant on the intrinsic value (the difference beteen strike and asset price), as there is less time and less chance for price to move a lot (variance). But the price of the option also has the extrinsic part which in turn is affected by time value.

In reverse, if there is a long time to expiery, the price difference between the price of the option and the intrinsic value could be much bigger, due to time value.

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/timevalue.asp

Comment: Hi! Thanks very much for your answer. I indeed accept that we usually think of the future as uncertain, but it seems to me that uncertainty about the future price of the underlying asset is literally the same thing as "volatility". Is there a meaningful way to distinguish those two? I think this is another way of expressing my original question really. Also, maybe I picked you up wrong, but when I say that the hypothetical no-volatility asset is deterministic, I don't necessarily regard that as implying that the price is "the same for each time" -- what did you mean by that? Thanks again

Comment: hi! when you say 'suppose first that we have a hypothetical asset with no volatility', I understand that as the price being constant. Also, the difference between two terms, maybe think of how volatility describes the past, as measure for predicting the future with a degree of certainty. 

If we see volatility some form of variance, this is usually calculated with some past window. (or any other measure if you want like another indicator or market).

Comment: Back to time-value, if we have no volatility, it becomes certain there is no change in price. with some volatility, the future is uncertain, leaving room for speculation. This is then part of the extrinsic value, affected by the amount of time remaining. So with more time, there is more potential in change of variance. If you set the change of variance to constant (being none in youur case) then there is no time value. But if the variance is unpredictable then that creates value for speculators, based on other factors like politics or buisness

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you say that: if i eliminate variance, the price can still change, so time value (based on variance) is not valid? 

i'm a bit confused with what you mean with a) asset with no volatility,  b) price Sm can change for a change in t. If the price changes, then that means there is volatility right?

the room for speculation, the change of Sm, is the time value. S should be constant, based on the intinsic value of the stock and the price gap of the option and the market.   However, S can vary more than that, which i see as influenced by the time value.

Comment: Hi Iloos, thanks very much for sticking with me on this. I'll try and clarify my thinking a bit and if you're inclined to let me know your thoughts after that, I'll be very grateful. First, to be more precise, although I accept that as you say volatility is usually measured from past fluctuations (this is a kind of "implied volatility" if I understand terms correctly), I want to think of it for the moment in the following more idealistic way: the (log of the) stock price is a stochastic process made up of a deterministic part plus a non-deterministic part

Comment: -- the latter is a product of Brownian motion rescaled by some factor, and I'm thinking of that scaling factor as the volatility. In my mind, the distinction between the deterministic and non-deterministic parts of the stock price is as follows: if we ran simulations (of the real world) many times based on the same fundamentals of the stock, then the deterministic component of the price would be the same every single time (because the fundamentals would be the same every single time), however the non-deterministic part would be slightly different each time as it behaves probabilistically

Comment: (this part I regard as the effects of politics, business, etc).

Comment: At this point, I would therefore take back my claim that volatility is the same thing as uncertainty about future price of the stock -- instead, I would like to claim that uncertainty about the underlying fundamentals contributes to uncertainty about the deterministic component of the stock price (so we can't predict the deterministic part unless we can predict the fundamentals, but nevertheless if the fundamentals are the same then the deterministic part should be the same) and the volatility then controls the possible changes in the non-deterministic part.

Comment: It is then a measure of the stock's sensitivity to the non-fundamental effects. In all this, I realize I'm assuming a reasonably well agreed-upon definition of "fundamentals" and feel free to correct me if that's a bad assumption.  Putting this together for now though, uncertainty about the future price therefore has two pieces -- uncertainty about the stock fundamentals, and the volatility.

Comment: Thus a zero-volatility hypothetical stock could have a changing price (but dependent solely on the fundamentals) and, in this case, the time-value of an option on that stock would presumably then be dependent solely on the market's expectation of how the stock's fundamentals will change before the option matures. To put it a different way, I would picture this as follows: if you take a graph of stock price over (a fairly long) time and plot a smooth best-fit curve through it,

Comment: then that best-fit curve is the deterministic part of the price and the little jumps/deviations between that and the true price form the non-deterministic piece. The volatility, in my mind, would be the average size of those jumps/deviations. So, finally then, the time-value of an option on a stock that does have some volatility would in part consist of the market's expectations of how the stocks fundamentals will change before the option matures (the deterministic part) and in other part consist of the value of hedging against jumps/deviations from that deterministic part that could,

Comment: if they were big enough, cause a large enough deviation to put the option "out of the money" (the non-deterministic part).

Comment: Having written and thought through all that, I expect you might tell me that much more often people just tend to think more simply of volatility as encompassing both of those two pieces?